# Why doesn't ConcurrentDictionary explicitly implement the Add method?

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

Why doesn't **ConcurrentDictionary** explicitly implement the Add method, since it is supposed to extend `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` which defines this method:

`void Add(TKey key, TValue value);`

I read that this is owed to "explicit interface implementation".

As far as I know, when I derive a class from an interface, I get an error for any interface method that I forget to implement in the class.

I noticed the similar question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation 
This link presumably contains a similar example of "explicit interface implementation" which is very easy to understand: a class inherits from 2 interfaces that define the same method;
in order to distinguish between the two different methods, in the class that derives from the two interfaces we have two methods each prefixed by the interface's name. Simple:

```
public class SampleClass : IControl, ISurface
{
    void IControl.Paint() // IControl interface defines method **Paint**
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
    }
    void ISurface.Paint() // ISurface interface defines another method, also called **Paint**
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("ISurface.Paint");
    }
}
```

This example doesn't showcase my scenario, because in my case in the ConcurrentDictionary I can't find the implementation of Add, prefixed or not by the interface name.
Any thoughts?

Comment: It does, so I read, but where exactly? I couldn't find it. Press F12 on ConcurrentDictionary, there is no Add method in sight. Is it somewhere in an extension class maybe?

Comment: Ever tried to read the property `IsReadOnly`? It is defined in [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.isreadonly)

Comment: _"in my case in the ConcurrentDictionary I can't find the implementation of Add"_ - then show how you search, because it's definitely there. You'll have to look at the documentation, or refer to a variable of type `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or decompile the class.

Comment: Here's the implementation: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Concurrent/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs#L1289

Comment: Just plainly F12 on ConcurrentDictionary keyword, CodeCaster. Interestingly enough, I do find the method `void IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)` here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,2e5ef5704344a309 , but why not with F12, which is what I always use to see the signatures??

Comment: With an explicit interface implementation, you *have* to call the member having cast the object to that interface. If you just have `var a = new ConcurrentDictionary ...` you *cannot* write `a.Add(...)` but you must write `((IDictionary)a).Add(...)` (or obviously you can store the result into a variable. Not sure what you have F12 shortcut for, but if it's showing you what you can call based on a *variable* then that may be why you're not seeing it.

Comment: The default Visual Studio F12 is Go To Definition, which'll show you the public members of a type.